# mitmproxy script can't connect to cosmos db

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mitmproxy

I am using proxy server using `mitmproxy` in Python.
It worked great, but when I tried connecting to Cosmos Client using the following code:

```py
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(cosmos_uri, key)
```

The script stuck and can't continue.
I am running the proxy using the command: `mitmweb -s python_code.py`.

I tried changing the location of when the connection is done (in `running` hook and in `done` hook), but it doesn't seem to change anything:

```py
class ChangeHTTPCode:
    def running(self):
        client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(cosmos_uri, key)

addons = [ChangeHTTPCode()]
```

Do you know why this connection might do that?

It's worth saying that when I ran this code outside the script (as a standalone script) it worked (with and without using the proxy).